# Make a login panel

Tags: java, swing, frame

I would like to make clearly that i do not ask somebody to write the code for me. This is useless for me and also annoying for you:

I have to do the following task. Create a Java Frame for some functions in my java project.
So here is the task:

The Main Panel has to look exactly like this:

[image: http://beepleased.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Capture.jpg]

When the user logins, i need to pop up a success message like "Well Done" and the HIDE on close. Simultaneously the button "Place Order" needs to be turned on so that someone will be able to press it from now on. And the Panel needs to look like this:

[image: http://beepleased.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1.jpg]

The Sign Up form has to look like this one:

When the user finish filling all those fields, presses "Sign Up" and as a result a new user is creating and assign at an ArrayList but this doesnt matter at the moment.( I need the graphics).  At the end ... all fields have to be cleared in order to fill new fields inside the Sign Up Form.

Form "PLace Order" need to look like :

where sb is able to make his order by purchasing products.

Finally, I need a JOptionPane like this:

I know that this may be an easy one but i want to do it by myself . The main reason i posted in here is to guide me throw this. By giving me some tutorial links, or some already build code for these. Something more like "search on Java Oracle Tutorials". 
What are the basic steps i need to know as a beginner in Java Frame Programming ? (GUI)

Thanks in advance, appreciate any help.

Comment: The other images are:
http://beepleased.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=519&action=edit

http://beepleased.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=520&action=edit

http://beepleased.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=521&action=edit

Thank you all :-)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: `By giving me some tutorial links,` - [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Maybe start with the sections on `How to Use Buttons` and `How to Use FlowLayout` for some basics.

Answer (score 1):

Some code to start with

```
package tsoukalis;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Tsoukalis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginPanel().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class LoginPanel extends JFrame {

    private JButton login, signUp, placeOrder;

    public LoginPanel() {
        super("Main Panel");
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        login = new JButton("Login");
        signUp = new JButton("Sign Up");
        placeOrder = new JButton("Place Order");

        add(login);
        add(signUp);
        add(placeOrder);

        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPanel.this, "Well Done");
                placeOrder.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        placeOrder.setEnabled(false);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]